# What keywords GLSL introduce to C?

Tags: glsl, syntax-highlighting, keyword

So we have in C:

```
auto if break int case long char register
continue return default short do sizeof 
double static else struct entry switch extern
typedef float union for unsigned 
goto while enum void const signed volatile
```

What new keywords OpenGL (ES) Shader Language provide to us?

I am new to GLSL and I want to create some [highlight editing util for ease of use](http://fiddle.jshell.net/t9sgA/8/).

Math words included into GLSL will count as keywords..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to get the OpenGL ES GLSL [language specification](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.Full.1.40.05.pdf). §3.6 lists the keywords (plus a number of reserved words that aren't keywords, but you're not supposed to use anyway, so they probably merit *some* sort of color coding as well).

Edit: Oops, I grabbed the wrong link there. My apologies. The current specs are:

[OpenGL 4.1 GLSL](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.4.10.6.clean.pdf)
[OpenGL ES 2.0 GLSL](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/2.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_1.0.17.pdf)

Comment: That link points at the OpenGL GLSL spec, not the ES one.  The GL spec is a superset of the ES spec, so is probably good for figuring out keywords.

Answer (score 10):

New ones (excluding the ones you listed above) according to the [latest spec document](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.4.00.8.clean.pdf):

> attribute uniform varying
>   layout
>   centroid flat smooth noperspective
>   patch sample
>   subroutine
>   in out inout
>   invariant
>   discard
>   mat2 mat3 mat4 dmat2 dmat3 dmat4
>   mat2x2 mat2x3 mat2x4 dmat2x2 dmat2x3 dmat2x4
>   mat3x2 mat3x3 mat3x4 dmat3x2 dmat3x3 dmat3x4
>   mat4x2 mat4x3 mat4x4 dmat4x2 dmat4x3 dmat4x4
>   vec2 vec3 vec4 ivec2 ivec3 ivec4 bvec2 bvec3 bvec4 dvec2 dvec3 dvec4
>   uvec2 uvec3 uvec4
>   lowp mediump highp precision
>   sampler1D sampler2D sampler3D samplerCube
>   sampler1DShadow sampler2DShadow samplerCubeShadow
>   sampler1DArray sampler2DArray
>   sampler1DArrayShadow sampler2DArrayShadow
>   isampler1D isampler2D isampler3D isamplerCube
>   isampler1DArray isampler2DArray
>   usampler1D usampler2D usampler3D usamplerCube
>   usampler1DArray usampler2DArray
>   sampler2DRect sampler2DRectShadow isampler2DRect usampler2DRect
>   samplerBuffer isamplerBuffer usamplerBuffer
>   sampler2DMS isampler2DMS usampler2DMS
>   sampler2DMSArray isampler2DMSArray usampler2DMSArray
>   samplerCubeArray samplerCubeArrayShadow isamplerCubeArray usamplerCubeArray

Reserved for future use (will cause error at the moment):

> common partition active
>   asm
>   class union enum typedef template this packed
>   goto
>   inline noinline volatile public static extern external interface
>   long short half fixed unsigned superp
>   input output
>   hvec2 hvec3 hvec4 fvec2 fvec3 fvec4
>   sampler3DRect
>   filter
>   image1D image2D image3D imageCube
>   iimage1D iimage2D iimage3D iimageCube
>   uimage1D uimage2D uimage3D uimageCube
>   image1DArray image2DArray
>   iimage1DArray iimage2DArray uimage1DArray uimage2DArray
>   image1DShadow image2DShadow
>   image1DArrayShadow image2DArrayShadow
>   imageBuffer iimageBuffer uimageBuffer
>   sizeof cast
>   namespace using
>   row_major

Answer (score 0):

Besides the above answers, there are also reserved identifiers, eg. in GLSL ES 3.0 [spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/3.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_3.00.pdf):

> Identifiers starting with `gl_` are reserved for use by OpenGL ES, and may not be declared in a shader as either a variable or a function. It is an error to redeclare a variable, including those starting “gl_”.

And other things beyond these are reserved:

> In addition, all identifiers containing two consecutive underscores (__) are reserved for use by underlying software layers. Defining such a name in a shader does not itself result in an error, but may result in unintended behaviors that stem from having multiple definitions of the same name.

It is relevant for syntax coloring and correctness checking.
Similarly, macros starting with `GL_`, and a bunch of things with `__`.